# Setting http headers with Angular 2 Typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, http-headers

I have some Angular 1 Javascript code I am trying to rewrite in Angular 2 Typescript.

I am stuck on how to write the Angular 2 Typescript version of:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Token ' + $cookies.token;
```

In my Typescript file I have the following import but can't find out how to set the headers or get the equivalent of `$cookies.token`.

```
import {Http, Headers, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
```

Answer (score 0):

I havent worked with cookies yet in angular 2 but this is how you ive set headers for a post request.

```
    let body = JSON.stringify(task);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    this.http.post('/Custom/Create', body, options)
        .subscribe(() => { }, err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

1.Import this code

```
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
```

2.Put this code in your Constructor

```
constructor(private http: Http) {}
```

3. And this code for Api call,

   ```
   var headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + YOUR COOKIE VARIABLE); // You can use, if you want to send cookies in your api call.

   this.http.post('http://**yourApiUrlHere**,{headers:headers})


    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
    data => {
      //Do something
    }
   ```